# Upgrading to new IPython notebook has caused problems for matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I'm not exactly sure what had gone wrong, but since upgrading my IPython notebook v3.0.0 today I am now getting a rather worrying error when calling plt.show():

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/iMacHome/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     57     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     58         before(artist, renderer)
---> 59         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     60         after(artist, renderer)
     61 

/Users/iMacHome/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.pyc in draw(self, renderer)
   1077         dsu.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
   1078         for zorder, a, func, args in dsu:
-> 1079             func(*args)
   1080 
   1081         renderer.close_group('figure')

/Users/iMacHome/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     57     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     58         before(artist, renderer)
---> 59         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     60         after(artist, renderer)
     61 

/Users/iMacHome/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.pyc in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2090 
   2091         for zorder, a in dsu:
-> 2092             a.draw(renderer)
   2093 
   2094         renderer.close_group('axes')

/Users/iMacHome/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     57     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     58         before(artist, renderer)
---> 59         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     60         after(artist, renderer)
     61 

/Users/iMacHome/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/legend.pyc in draw(self, renderer)
    448         # update the location and size of the legend. This needs to
    449         # be done in any case to clip the figure right.
--> 450         bbox = self._legend_box.get_window_extent(renderer)
    451         self.legendPatch.set_bounds(bbox.x0, bbox.y0,
    452                                     bbox.width, bbox.height)

/Users/iMacHome/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/offsetbox.pyc in get_window_extent(self, renderer)
    254         get the bounding box in display space.
    255         '''
--> 256         w, h, xd, yd, offsets = self.get_extent_offsets(renderer)
    257         px, py = self.get_offset(w, h, xd, yd, renderer)
    258         return mtransforms.Bbox.from_bounds(px - xd, py - yd, w, h)

/Users/iMacHome/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/offsetbox.pyc in get_extent_offsets(self, renderer)
    375 
    376         whd_list = [c.get_extent(renderer)
--> 377                     for c in self.get_visible_children()]
    378         whd_list = [(w, h, xd, (h - yd)) for w, h, xd, yd in whd_list]
    379 

/Users/iMacHome/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/offsetbox.pyc in get_extent(self, renderer)
    247         Return with, height, xdescent, ydescent of box
    248         """
--> 249         w, h, xd, yd, offsets = self.get_extent_offsets(renderer)
    250         return w, h, xd, yd
    251 

/Users/iMacHome/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/offsetbox.pyc in get_extent_offsets(self, renderer)
    446 
    447         whd_list = [c.get_extent(renderer)
--> 448                     for c in self.get_visible_children()]
    449 
    450         if not whd_list:

/Users/iMacHome/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/offsetbox.pyc in get_extent(self, renderer)
    247         Return with, height, xdescent, ydescent of box
    248         """
--> 249         w, h, xd, yd, offsets = self.get_extent_offsets(renderer)
    250         return w, h, xd, yd
    251 

/Users/iMacHome/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/offsetbox.pyc in get_extent_offsets(self, renderer)
    375 
    376         whd_list = [c.get_extent(renderer)
--> 377                     for c in self.get_visible_children()]
    378         whd_list = [(w, h, xd, (h - yd)) for w, h, xd, yd in whd_list]
    379 

/Users/iMacHome/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/offsetbox.pyc in get_extent(self, renderer)
    247         Return with, height, xdescent, ydescent of box
    248         """
--> 249         w, h, xd, yd, offsets = self.get_extent_offsets(renderer)
    250         return w, h, xd, yd
    251 

/Users/iMacHome/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/offsetbox.pyc in get_extent_offsets(self, renderer)
    446 
    447         whd_list = [c.get_extent(renderer)
--> 448                     for c in self.get_visible_children()]
    449 
    450         if not whd_list:

/Users/iMacHome/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/offsetbox.pyc in get_extent(self, renderer)
    778         clean_line, ismath = self._text.is_math_text(self._text._text)
    779         _, h_, d_ = renderer.get_text_width_height_descent(
--> 780             "lp", self._text._fontproperties, ismath=False)
    781 
    782         bbox, info, d = self._text._get_layout(renderer)

/Users/iMacHome/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py in get_text_width_height_descent(self, s, prop, ismath)
    164         size = self.points_to_pixels(points)
    165         width, height, descent = self.gc.get_text_width_height_descent(
--> 166             six.text_type(s), family, size, weight, style)
    167         return  width, height, 0.0*descent
    168 

ValueError: failed to convert font family name to ASCII
```

This messes up the dynamic editor, which doesn't display the full plot correctly. And then when saving the file, it looks fine. It's just not being displayed in the dynamic plt.show() view correctly?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this problem arises from changing the font family from within the legend properties argument.

So, instead of:

```
axHistX.legend(loc='upper left',  prop={'family':'serif', 'size':'x-small'})
```

You need to use:

```
axHistX.legend(loc='upper left', prop={'size':8})
```

Combined with the global property change of:

```
mpl.rc('font',family='serif')
```